# Can propensity score matching be used in nested case-control study?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, case-control-study

I'm poor with epidemiological methodology and I'm working on a study that look at the effects of a binary exposure on three time-to-event outcomes in a large cohort (general population). As the outcome being rare (seems to be a nested case-control or retrospective study), could it be possible (or plausible) to extract exposure/control groups for each outcome in this large cohort based on propensity score matching?

I know PSM may be more appliable for a cohort study rather than a case-control study. But for a large cohort with rare outcomes, could PSM still works? Or in other words, would PSM result in none event both in exposure and control groups?

Comment: 1) Are you gonna look at these outcomes separately or together? If you decide to look at them together you will get into the "competing risk" survival. 2)if the outcome is rare you don't need to worry about PSM or nested case-control, those are useful only if the exposure is also rare so you need to pick controls carefully, but otherwise you might just do a normal cohort analysis

Comment: Thanks to jmarkov. The outcomes in this study should be considered separately, so the "competing risk" may be not appliable. For point 2, I'm still confused. Does this mean that I build three separate regressions based on the same dataset (only outcome variable differs, and assuming the same exclusion criteria)?

Comment: Where is the nesting?  And, yes, you should use three different regressions. Probably Cox proportional hazard since you have time to event (that usually has censoring).  Also, I'm confused. Are you trying to decide on a design? Or do you have one?

Comment: Thanks to Peter Flom. I have a cohort with about 6 years follow-up. I'm being told that the nested case-control is appliable for rare outcome, and I want to reduce the potential confounding and reach the causal estimation. Thus I wonder if it appliable to use PSM.

Comment: You need the nested case-control usually when you have a limited number of controls you can select from or when you need to match characteristics of control and cases accurately. I don't see a reason why you should use it in your case! If you have availabity of the entire cohort dataset, I agree Cox proportional hazard model can be what you are looking for. Its underlying design is a case-control with cases and controls matched in time (or so-called timescale).

Comment: However, these are not easy topics and if you don't enough preparation and experience you would probably be more safe to receive serious help throughout your entire analysis.

Comment: Whatever you do, don’t use a matching method to excludes valid observations.  That’s not really scientific.

Comment: Many thanks to jmarkov and Frank Harrell.